# Match multiple times a group in a string

Tags: python, regex

i'am trying to use regular expression. I have this string that has to be matched

```
 influences = 
 {{hlist |[[Plato]] |[[Aristotle]] |[[Socrates]] |[[David Hume]] |[[Adam Smith]] |[[Cicero]] |[[John Locke]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Saint Augustine]] |[[Saint Thomas Aquinas]] |[[Saint Thomas More]] |[[Richard Hooker]] |[[Edward Coke]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Thomas Hobbes]] |[[Rene Descartes]] |[[Montesquieu]] |[[Joshua Reynolds]] |[[Sir William Blackstone|William Blackstone]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Niccolo Machiavelli]] |[[Dante Alighieri]] |[[Samuel Johnson]] |[[Voltaire]] |[[Jean Jacques Rousseau]] |[[Jeremy Bentham]]}}
```

I would like to extract from the text the following templates:

```
{{hlist .... }}
```

Instead, the following text has not to be matched:

```
main_interests = 
 {{hlist |[[Music]] |[[Art]] |[[Theatre]] |[[Literature]]}}
```

I wrote this regex but it doesn't work

```
(?:^\|\s*)?(?:influences)\s*?=\s*?(?:(?:\s*\{\{hlist)\s*\|([\d\w\s\-()*—&;\[\]|#%.<>·:/",\'!{}=•?’
á~ü°œéö$àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]*?)(?=\n))+
```

I'm using python.

Comment: Do you want just the text after the `hlist` or do you want to get the list of names without the brackets?

Comment: I would like to take the text after the hlist inside the brackets. Moreover, since the hlist tags may appear in other fields (see the example above with main_interests) i would like to sure that the text i'm matching belong to a precise field (e.g. influnces).

Comment: You can use the regex `influences\\s*=(?:\\s*{{hlist(?:\\s*\\|\\[\\[([^]]+)\\]\\])+}})*`. It will capture the text as asked. Using C# you can get all captures of a group using `matches[0].Groups[1].Captures`.

Comment: The regex works but it only takes the last value contained in the square brackets (see https://regex101.com/r/iN7uL9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with some regular expressions:

```
import re
string = """
influences = 
 {{hlist |[[Plato]] |[[Aristotle]] |[[Socrates]] |[[David Hume]] |[[Adam Smith]] |[[Cicero]] |[[John Locke]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Saint Augustine]] |[[Saint Thomas Aquinas]] |[[Saint Thomas More]] |[[Richard Hooker]] |[[Edward Coke]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Thomas Hobbes]] |[[Rene Descartes]] |[[Montesquieu]] |[[Joshua Reynolds]] |[[Sir William Blackstone|William Blackstone]]}}
 {{hlist |[[Niccolo Machiavelli]] |[[Dante Alighieri]] |[[Samuel Johnson]] |[[Voltaire]] |[[Jean Jacques Rousseau]] |[[Jeremy Bentham]]}}
"""

matches = [template.group(1) 
           for match in re.findall(r'\{\{hlist.+?\}}', string)
           for template in re.finditer(r'\[\[([^]]+)\]\]', match)]
print(matches)
# ['Plato', 'Aristotle', 'Socrates', 'David Hume', 'Adam Smith', 'Cicero', 'John Locke', 'Saint Augustine', 'Saint Thomas Aquinas', 'Saint Thomas More', 'Richard Hooker', 'Edward Coke', 'Thomas Hobbes', 'Rene Descartes', 'Montesquieu', 'Joshua Reynolds', 'Sir William Blackstone|William Blackstone', 'Niccolo Machiavelli', 'Dante Alighieri', 'Samuel Johnson', 'Voltaire', 'Jean Jacques Rousseau', 'Jeremy Bentham']
```

This uses two expressions, one for the outer part (`{{hlist...}}`) and another one for the inner part (`[[...]]`).

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](http://ideone.com/B7r3Tz).

Comment: Your regular expression will match also if the influences tag at the beginning of the string is not absent.

Comment: @JacopoTerrinoni: Not absent?

Comment: Not contained in the string.

Comment: @JacopoTerrinoni: Please provide more input strings which shall and shall not be matched.